# More efficient to do SELECT and compare in Java or DELETE and INSERT

Tags: java, database, spring, postgresql, jpa

I am hitting a REST API to get data from a service. I transform this data and store it in a database. I will have to do this on some interval, 15 minutes, and then make sure this database has latest information.
I am doing this in a Java program. I am wondering if it would be better, after I have queried all data, to do
1. SELECT statements and compare vs transformed data and do UPDATEs (DELETE all associated records to what was changed and INSERT new)

OR

2. DELETE ALL and INSERT ALL every time.

Option 1 has potential to be a lot less transactions, guaranteed SELECT on all records because we are comparing, but potentially not a lot of UPDATEs since I don't expect data to be changing much. But it has downside of doing comparisons on all records to detect a change

I am planning on doing this using Spring Boot, JPA layer and possibly postgres

Comment: Insert with on conflict also gives a solution, dont know benchmark of any

Comment: What's the expected data volume?

Comment: Please do [not crosspost](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/64068/157328)

Comment: Can the SELECT include a WHERE clause to fetch the records which need to be updated?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short answer is "It depends.  Test and see *for your usecase*."

The longer answer: this feels like preoptimization.  And the general response for preoptimization is "don't."  Especially in DB realms like this, what would be best in one situation can be awful in another.  There are a number of factors, including (and not exclusive to) schema, indexes, HDD backing speed, concurrency, amount of data, network speed, latency, and so on:

1. First, get it working
2. Identify what's wrong → get a metric
3. Measure against that metric
4. Make any obvious or necessary changes
5. Repeat 1 through 4 as appropriate

The first question I would ask of you is "What does *better* mean?"  Once you define that, the path forward will likely become clearer.